# ios - Images in table cell view not having proper size at runtime and self changing size and clipping bounds when I scroll

Tags: ios, swift, view

When I run my app on the `simulator` the images that I load via a http request don't have proper sizing and bounds clip. I want them to a size `60x60` with a round shape, but instead they scale to fit the `UITableViewCell` kinda randomly but after I scroll up and down they remain fixed but still to big, I don't know what causes this neither do I know how to fix it, I'm new to `iOS`.I will post a screenshot with my `UIImageView` in Table Cell and with the effect that it has when I first run the app and my `View Controller` class.

I have tried to mess with the constraints, set fixed width and height constraint on the `UIImageView` but with no result.
I also tried to disable **subview auto resize** from the cell view but with no result.

This is the effect,this happens before I start scrolling:

[image]

This happens after I scroll up and down,the clipping on bounds returns to normal but the size is still to big:

[image]

This is my storyboard with the cell image view:

[image]

And this is my ViewController.swift class :

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TopDevelopers
//
//  Created by Eduard Valentin on 12/04/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Eduard Valentin. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Foundation

struct UserInfo {
    var name:String
    var imageURL:String
    var imageView:UIImageView

    init(newName: String, newImageURL:String, newImageView: UIImageView) {
    self.name = newName
    self.imageURL = newImageURL
    self.imageView = newImageView

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var users:[UserInfo] = []



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // GET the data from the stackexchange api

    let param: Parameters = [
        "order": "desc",
        "max" : 10,
        "sort" : "reputation",
        "site" : "stackoverflow"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users", method: .get, parameters: param).responseJSON { (response) -> (Void) in


        if let json = response.result.value {
            // we got a result

            /* I know this is a bit ugly */
            let json1 = json as! [String:AnyObject]
            let usersInfoFromJSON = json1["items"] as! NSArray       // remember to cast it as NSDictionary


            for userInfo in usersInfoFromJSON {

                let userDict = userInfo as! NSDictionary

                Alamofire.request(userDict["profile_image"] as! String).responseData { (response) in
                    if response.error == nil {
                        print(response.result)
                        // Show the downloaded image:
                        if let data = response.data {
                            let imageView = UIImageView()
                            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                            self.users.append(UserInfo(newName: userDict["display_name"] as! String,
                                                       newImageURL: userDict["profile_image"] as! String,newImageView: imageView))
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.users.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.cellImageView.image = self.users[indexPath.row].imageView.image
    cell.cellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.cellImageView.layer.frame.height / 2)
    cell.cellLabel.text = self.users[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**EDIT 1:** 
I also tried to set content mode to "scale to fit", "aspect fit" still the same results.

**EDIT 2:** Ok, I solved it by just deleting almost everything and doing it all over again but this time I did set the option for the "Suggested constraints", also I used xib's for the cells and everything is normal now, I still don't know what caused it.

Comment: Have you tried setting you image content mode to scale to fir from storyboard.?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, It's still the same

Comment: Why are you using custom cell? In UITableView basic cell provide default imageview and label

Comment: I followed a tutorial and they used custom cell

Comment: Are you placing them using a StackView by any chance?

Comment: @Super_Simon I'm placing them inside Table View

Comment: @byJeevan ' maskToBounds ' is not a property of UIImageView, at least that's what xcode says, if you meant " clipToBounds = true ", I have tried that, no result

Comment: @Kuldeep yes,I set it viewcontroller

Comment: Remove top constraint and also 

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}`

Comment: @Kamran top constraint of the image ?

Comment: @EduardValentin Yes

Comment: Have you tried with with cell.cellImageView.layer.maskToBounds = true

Comment: @EduardValentin, if your `heightForRowAt` is fixed than set `UIImageView` `constraint` something like this.  `Leading of Cell` `Centre Vertically of Cell` `Equal Height Of Cell` `Aspect Ration 1:1` and than decrease `UIImageView` `Equal Height` constraint from `1` to `0.6`.

Comment: @Kuldeep doesn't work, I don't know if i get it right

Answer (score 0):

Set `clipsToBounds` property to `true`, and set frames according to cellImageView's frame rather cellImageView.layer's frame:

```
cell.cellImageView.clipsToBounds = true 
cell.cellImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
cell.cellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cellImageView.frame.height / 2
```

And try to add `UIImage` in your struct rather than `UIImageView`. And use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as:

```
cell.cellImageView.image = self.users[indexPath.row].image
```

Comment: It is set in the storyboard, I had it set in view controler to , it doesn't change anything

Comment: @EduardValentin, have you tried adding `UIImage` in your struct rather than `UIImageView` ?

Comment: Sure, in a bit I will put ti on github

Answer (score -1):

In your case do not use CustomCell, because basic tableviewcell provide default `UIImageView` and `UILable`

Update inside cellForRowAt function with below code

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIndentifier")
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    cell.imageView?.image = self.users[indexPath.row].imageView.image
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView?.frame.width / 2
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I did that but images have the same effect

Comment: Try to set cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Comment: Tried, no result